# Finding the largest and second largest number

Tags: c

> Write a program that inputs a series of 10 numbers and find the 2 largest values of the 10 numbers? (Only using if and loop)

Can anybody help me to solve the problem?. I tried to but it was not right. It cannot list out the second largest number. Any helps would be appreciated.

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>
  #include <math.h>


int main()
{
    int counter = 0, number, largest = 0,largest2=0;
    for (counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
        printf("Enter number (%d): ", counter);
        scanf_s("%d", &number);
        if (number > largest)
        {
            largest = number;
        }
        else
        {
            if (number > largest2)
                largest2 = number;
        }
    }
    printf("The largest number is %d\n", largest);
    printf("The second largest number is %d\n", largest2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: btw you should to use "INT_MIN" for the largest init - what if I will wrote -10,-11,.. as input? 
From init on zero, you will get 0 as the largest, but thats not true :)
look on constancts eg. there https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/limits.h

Comment: How do you expect repeated values to be handled?  For example, what output do you expect for input  "9 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10"?  Depending on definition, the second largest value is either 9 or 10.

Comment: Sorry I forgot. "Each number is inputted only once"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic must be refined:

- When you get a new largest number, you must update the second largest as well, since the previous largest number becomes the second largest.
- Furthermore, you should initialize the largest and second largest to `INT_MIN` so you can handle negative numbers correctly.
- You must also check the return value of `scanf_s()` and exit if the user fails to enter a number.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int number, largest = INT_MIN, largest2 = INT_MIN;

    for (int counter = 1; counter <= 10; counter++) {
        printf("Enter number %d: ", counter);
        if (scanf_s("%d", &number) != 1) {
            printf("input failure\n");
            return 1;
        }
        if (number > largest) {
            largest2 = largest;
            largest = number;
        } else
        if (number > largest2) {
            largest2 = number;
        }
    }
    printf("The largest number is %d\n", largest);
    printf("The second largest number is %d\n", largest2);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

When you get a new largest number, the old largest number become the second largest number. So all you need is a single check for the largest number, and two assignments.

Something like

```
if (number > largest)
{
    largest2 = largest;
    largest = number;
}
```

You still need to check for numbers larger than `largest2`.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code:

```
if (number > largest)
    {
    largest = number;
    }
```

you throw away the known largest number, while that number should become the second largest number. So you should add the line largest2 = largest.

Note: By initializing largest and largest2 to zero the algorithm won't work for negative numbers.

Answer (score 1):

if `number` is greater than `largest`, you should update `largest2` too, because now that you found a number greater than any previous ones, `largest` becomes the second largest number!

```
    if (number > largest)
    {
        largest = number;
    }
```

becomes

```
    if (number > largest)
    {
        largest2 = largest;
        largest = number;
    }
```